# How to get notification only for few items from signalR? (EF core and Angular 8)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, signalr

In our .Net core and Angular 8 application, we have implemented SignalR. We need real time notification on different events.

Events (in our application) is a dynamically created item. (Birthday event, anniversary event, etc)

Let's say Users can open any event. And Few polls and chat are in progress. Whenever users change something in an event, I need to notify other clients who have opened same event.

Currently, the notification from all the events hit all the clients (irrespective of events that they have opened)

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub    {
    public async Task UpdateVote(int eventId, int pollId, int pollOptionId)
    {
        await Clients.Others.SendAsync("VoteUpdated", eventId, pollId, pollOptionId);
    }
}
```

Angular:

```
private CreateConnection() {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(environment.base + 'NotificationHub')
      .build();
  }

  private StartConnection(): void {
    this._hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        this.connectionIsEstablished = true;
        console.log('Hub connection started');
        this.connectionEstablished.emit(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while establishing connection, retrying...');
        setTimeout(function () { this.StartConnection(); }, 5000);
      });
  }

UpdateVote(eventId, pollId, pollOptionId) {
    this._hubConnection.invoke('UpdateVote', eventId, pollId, pollOptionId);
  }

private RegisterOnServerEvents(): void {
    this._hubConnection.on('VoteUpdated', (eventId, pollId, pollOptionId) => {
      this.VoteUpdated.emit({ eventId, pollId, pollOptionId });
    });
  }
```

I am opening connection on load of the website.

**What do I need to implement so that the clients are notified only about the events that they have opened?**

Comment: Add them in a Group. Like Whenever a user visits an Event add them to a group like ```"Event-" + eventId``` and when ever a change occurs notify that group only.
Remember to remove from group when they close that page

Comment: @NoobCoder I suggest to you to add an answer, 'cause it's the right approach

Comment: @alessandro added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them in a Group. Like Whenever a user visits an Event add them to a group like "Event-" + eventId and when ever a change occurs notify that group only. Remember to remove from group when they close that page

```
public async AddToTrackGroup(string eventId) {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "event-" + eventId);
}

public async Task UpdateEventViewer(string eventId)
{
    Clients.Group("event-" + eventId).notifyEventChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly! 
For some reason, It showed "AddToGroupAsync" and "RemoveFromGroupAsync" as the functions. Probably version is different. But I got the idea. Now I am notifying only targeted clients using "Clients.OthersInGroup".

Comment: Yes this was just a pseudo code. I am glad its working for you